# How would you go about setting up middleware testing in Django?

Tags: django, testing, middleware

Starting to use unit tests for testing in Django and wanted to know the best practices of setting up middleware testing. Main concern is how do we test indivudual middleware classes and  also test them in the order that they actually execute when calling a view?